# Adding files to a docker instance not working

Tags: docker

I have the following snippet in my docker file:

```
...
 ADD app.war /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.14/webapps/app.war
...
```

However, entering the docker image as:

```
docker exec -it tomcat /bin/sh
```

and doing an `ls` to the `webapps` folder, the file isn't there. The file, in my local OS, windows, it is in the same folder as the dockerfile. Any clue about why this happens?

EDIT:
However, using the `cp` command in my windows cmd, it works correctly after checking in the container.

The dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER Adilson Cesar <adilsonbna@gmail.com>

# Expose Web Port
EXPOSE 8080

# Set environment
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
ENV JAVA_PACKAGE server-jre

ENV TOMCAT_VERSION_MAJOR 8
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL  8.5.14
ENV CATALINA_HOME /opt/tomcat

# Download and install Java
RUN apk --update add openjdk8-jre &&\
    mkdir -p /opt/jdk &&\
    ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin /opt/jdk

# Download and install Tomcat
RUN apk add --update curl &&\
  curl -LO https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_MAJOR}/v${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL}.tar.gz &&\
  curl -LO https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_MAJOR}/v${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL}.tar.gz.md5 &&\
  md5sum -c apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL}.tar.gz.md5 &&\
  gunzip -c apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL}.tar.gz | tar -xf - -C /opt &&\
  rm -f apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL}.tar.gz apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL}.tar.gz.md5 &&\
  ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION_FULL} /opt/tomcat &&\
  rm -rf /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs &&\
  apk del curl &&\
  rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

 ADD app.war /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.14/webapps/

# Launch Tomcat on startup
CMD ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh run
```

Thanks!

Comment: What command/compose file are you using to run your container?

Answer (score 2):

Although docker docs suggest otherwise

`If <dest> does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of <src> will be written at <dest>`

Try this by removing the destination filename. It should work.

```
ADD app.war /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.14/webapps/
```

---

Also, from [Docker Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) it is advised to use COPY instead of ADD if you're just copying local files and not playing around with remote URLs.

`Although ADD and COPY are functionally similar, generally speaking, COPY is preferred. That’s because it’s more transparent than ADD`

Comment: It unfortunately, didn't work. I updated the post with my dockerfile.

Comment: I tried a simple dockerfile with just the ```ADD``` command. It worked.
Trying with all the installations now. Let's see.